# Integrating with respect to a probability measure

Tags: probability

Let $X\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^k$ be a random variable in some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.

An integration with respect to a probability measure is denoted $\int_{\Omega}X d\mathbb{P}$.

What does this mean?

Comment: It is the component-wise integration.  You can think of $X$ as a random vector $X=(X_1, ..., X_k)$ and then that integral is $E[X] = (E[X_1], ..., E[X_k])$.

Answer (score 0):

One can think of $X$ as also pushing forward the measure $\mathbb{P}$ to $R^k$.  Then 
$$
\int_{\Omega} X d \mathbb{P}
$$
can be thought of as the standard integral on $\mathbb{R}^k$ with this pushed forward measure.

Answer (score 0):

If you interpret the probability measure as a weight distribution of mass, for each value of X. Then what you get is the mass center or the mean value of $X$ with respect to the measure $P$. This integral is however more complex that that in that you can have points with a mass as well in case X has discrete parts. The integral is general enough to cover both point masses and continuous distributions.